# How to set default value for fields in odoo 8?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I created a checkbox and I want to set its default value to false so that it is unchecked by default.I tried in four ways but still the checkbox is checked by default.

```
raw = fields.Boolean(default=0)
raw = fields.Boolean(default='0')
raw = fields.Boolean(default=False)
raw = fields.Boolean(default='False')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default it's None for boolean field not False(you can check into the database without setting up default value of any boolean field, you will see there None not False), so you just need to set like that

```
raw = fields.Boolean(string='Raw', default=False)
```

Comment: @Bhanukiran your solution no. 3 was already `default=False`, so why is this the right answer?

Comment: I didn't know that default value is None.I thought default value for boolean is True

Answer (score 2):

By default value of  Boolean field is false so you don't need to set it default value.

Now regarding your query :

```
raw = fields.Boolean(default='0')
raw = fields.Boolean(default='False')
```

Both these syntax are using **string** '0' and 'False' which is **True by logic**

you can use

```
raw = fields.Boolean(default=0)
raw = fields.Boolean(default=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an option too:

```
def default_value(self)
    <code here>
    return something
var = fields.Integer(default=default_value)
```